# function to style specific words on a given string utf-8?

Tags: php, utf-8, preg-replace

How to style specific words from a given string ?
i hyave a function to style specific words from a given string but this is not working in utf-8 string

```
 header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
function bold($string, $word)
{
    return preg_replace('/\b'.$word.'\b/', '<strong>'.$word.'</strong>', $string);
}

echo bold('چمستان تا', 'تا');
```

How can i do this ? I need to bold some keyword / phrases in the search resut based on typed user query

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Try `'/\b'.$word.'\b/u'`

Comment: error : Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: invalid UTF-8 string at offset 2

Comment: are you sure your file is saved in `utf-8` encoding?

Comment: Then try `'/(?<!\w)' . preg_quote($word,'/') . '(?!\w)/u'`

Comment: no my page is saved with ANSI after save with utf-8 your regex is worked thanks

Comment: this regex so worked /(?<!\w)' . preg_quote($word,'/') . '(?!\w)/u which one is better

Comment: The `\b` solution won't work if your search word starts or ends with a non-word char (punctuation, symbol, etc). I posted 3 alternative solutions just in case `\b` stops working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that:

- Your pages are saved with UTF8 encoding
- Add `/u` modifier
- Better `preg_quote` the search word just in case

Use

```
preg_replace('/\b'.preg_quote($word,'/').'\b/u', '<strong>'.$word.'</strong>', $string);
```

As an alternative to `\b`, you may use non-ambiguous word boundaries (no word char before or after the search word are allowed):

```
preg_replace('/(?<!\w)'.preg_quote($word,'/').'(?!\w)/u', '<strong>'.$word.'</strong>', $string);
```

or - to enforce the match inside whitespaces:

```
preg_replace('/(?<!\S)'.preg_quote($word,'/').'(?!\S)/u', '<strong>'.$word.'</strong>', $string);
```

Comment: function bold($string, $word)
{
    return preg_replace('/(?<!\S)'.preg_quote($word,'/').'(?!\S)/u', '<strong>'.$word.'</strong>', $string);
}
echo bold('hello world', 'hello wo');    why this is not work but when i remove "wo" is worked

Comment: It does not work, becaue `hello wo` requires a space or end of string after `wo`. There is no space or end of string in `hello world`. See https://ideone.com/CGX8Pa

Comment: when i search a word in google my word in bolded in google search results can you creat a function like google for me?

Comment: Haven't I answered your question? Is the question about re-creating Google?

Comment: no thank you for your answers. i dont want to re-creating google just i cant speack english well and i cant ask my question